# How to integrate $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+x^2)^3}} dx$ with substitution:$ x = tan(\alpha)$

Tags: integration

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+x^2)^3}} dx$$ with substitution:$$ x = \tan(\alpha)$$

Comment: Just substitute it and change $dx=\sec^2\alpha d\alpha$

Comment: This is something I read about in different Forums, but I don't have the knowledge to do it your way. It has to be solved in a different way.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it has to be solved in a different way'? Do you mean without the substitution of $x=\tan\alpha$?

Comment: It's *much* simpler with $x=\sinh t$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of subtle things going on here that are often overlooked in an undergraduate calculus course. Often, the naive solution will yield the same results as the more detailed solution and so there is an almost valid argument that we shouldn't go into such details at an introductory level. I will show you the naive solution first. Then I will go into the detailed solution.

**The naive solution.**

---

If $x = \tan \alpha$,
then $dx = \sec^2 \alpha \; d\alpha$
and $1 + x^2 = 1 + \tan^2 \alpha = \sec^2 \alpha$

\begin{align}
    \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+x^2)^3}} \: dx
    &= \int \frac{\sec^2 \alpha}{\sqrt{\sec^6 \alpha}} \: d\alpha \\
    &= \int \frac{\sec^2 \alpha}{\sec^3 \alpha} \: d\alpha \\
    &= \int \cos \alpha \: d\alpha \\
    &= \sin \alpha + C
\end{align}

\begin{align}
    \sec^2 \alpha &= 1 + x^2  \\
    cos^2 \alpha &= \dfrac{1}{1 + x^2} \\
    \sin^2 \alpha &= 1 - \dfrac{1}{1 + x^2} \\
    \sin^2 \alpha &= \dfrac{x^2}{1 + x^2} \\
    \sin \alpha &= \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}
\end{align}

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+x^2)^3}} \: dx = \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}} + C$$

**The detailed solution**

---

Let $x = \tan \alpha$.

For every real number, $x$ there are an infinite number of $\alpha's$ for which $x = \tan \alpha$. As much as possible, we want for there to be a one-to-one correspondece between the exes and the alphas. There is already a function that does that for us.

where $\alpha = \arctan x$

The range of $\arctan$ is $\alpha \in \left( -\dfrac{\pi}{2}, \dfrac{\pi}{2} \right)$ and the domain is $x \in (-\infty, \infty)$.

So we have managed to take care of all of the exes; but it is very important to notice that we are only using the alphas that are in the first and fourth quadrants (and the positive x-axis). This will be important later.

then $dx = \sec^2 \alpha \; d\alpha$
and $1 + x^2 = 1 + \tan^2 \alpha = \sec^2 \alpha$

$$ \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+x^2)^3}} \: dx = 
   \int \frac{\sec^2 \alpha}{\sqrt{\sec^6 \alpha}} \: d\alpha $$

Since $\alpha \in \left( -\dfrac{\pi}{2}, \dfrac{\pi}{2} \right)$ we know that $\sec \alpha > 0$. This is good for two reasons.

1. We don't need to worry about $\sec \alpha = 0$
2. We can say $\sqrt{\sec^6 \alpha} = \sec^3 \alpha$ because we know that the right side is a positive number.

\begin{align}
    \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+x^2)^3}} \: dx
    &= \int \frac{\sec^2 \alpha}{\sec^3 \alpha} \: d\alpha \\
    &= \int \cos \alpha \: d\alpha \\
    &= \sin \alpha + C
\end{align}

Now we need to express this solution in terms of $x$.

\begin{align}
    \sec^2 \alpha &= 1 + x^2  \\
    cos^2 \alpha &= \dfrac{1}{1 + x^2} \\
    \sin^2 \alpha &= 1 - \dfrac{1}{1 + x^2} \\
    \sin^2 \alpha &= \dfrac{x^2}{1 + x^2} \\
\end{align}

We want to say therefore
$$\sin \alpha = \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}$$

but we need to justify that:

1. When $\alpha$ is in the first quadrant, $\sin \alpha$ needs to be positive.
2. When $\alpha = 0$, $\sin \alpha$ needs to be $0$.
3. When $\alpha$ is in the fourth quadrant, $\sin \alpha$ needs to be negative.

All three of these requirements are true as a consequence of $x = \tan \alpha$.

And so

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+x^2)^3}} \: dx = \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}} + C$$

Comment: You have to convert the $\alpha$ back into $x$

Comment: allright guys, thats exactly the problem I told you so. I don't know the meaning of sec.

Comment: And why isn't $$dx = 1+ tan^2(x)$$? or is it?

Comment: "I don't know the meaning of sec": Well, $\sec x = \frac{1}{\cos x}$, and $1+\tan^2(x)=sec^2(x)$. That last identity is derived from the fact that $\sin^2(x)+cos^2(x)=1$. Just divide both sides by cosine to get $\frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}+1=\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)},$ and consequently that $\tan^2(x)+1=sec^2(x)$

Comment: @classMate - It is usually less confusing to convert everything into sine, cosine, and tangent. But sometimes cosecant, secant, and cotangent have to be dealt with as they are.

Comment: @ Steven Gregory - I'm just curious why my whole class don't work with them  - not even know them yet. Is this a mathematician thing or do engineers this too?

Comment: @classMate In my experience, it's a time thing. The instructors are required to cover so much material that they are forced to cut corners to get through all of it. Like it or not, the best thing you can do is take control of your own education and read/study/agonize over the book.

Comment: I'll try to heed your advice, thanks!

Comment: @classMate - I'm not kidding about the agonize part. It's impossible for a textbook to cater to the needs of every possible student. There is more to learning how to read than you might have imagined.

Answer (score 0):

The short solution: with $x=\tan\alpha$, $x^2+1=\dfrac1{\cos^2(\alpha)}$, $dx=\dfrac{d\alpha}{\cos^2(\alpha)}$, and

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+x^2)^3}} dx=\int\frac{\cos^3(\alpha)}{\cos^2(\alpha)}d\alpha=\sin(\alpha)+C.$$

Comment: this works for me too, thanks